# How to make a new list of dicts from an old one in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I have this list:

```
l1 = [{ 'likes': 10, 'dislikes': 1, 'title': u'sometext'}, {''likes': 7, dislikes': 5, 'title': u'other text'}]
```

Now I want to replace `likes` and `dislkes` with a `score`, so that `score = likes - dislikes`

The result should be:

```
l2 = [{'score': 9, 'title': u'sometext'}, {'score': 2, 'title': u'other text'}]
```

I'm wondering how best to do this in python 2.7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
l2 = [{'score': (el['likes'] - el['dislikes']), 'title': el['title']} for el in l1]
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `el['likes']` and `el['dislikes']` ?